# Swipe-Layout using PyGTK

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygtk

I would like to implement a swipe or flipper view (widget) using PyGtk for my Quickly app. There should be a titlebar that contains the title of the currently showed content and the titles of the previous and next entry. To navigate threw the different entries you should be able to click the titles or swipe from left to right or vice versa.

But I do not know where to start.

1. Which Widget should I extend?
2. Would the Notebook widget the right choice?
3. How could I change the style of a Widget?
4. How do I implement the flip effect?
5. Do I have to combine different views (widgets) for the content pane and the titlebar?

For a better understanding of my problem view the screenshot below.

Thanks and best regards

Andreas

[image: FlipperView]

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [Clutter](https://clutter-project.org/). Though I think, this kind of UI-Design could be very unintuitive on a desktop machine.

Comment: Thanks! Clutter looks very exciting and it is really interesting for developers. I will probably study more about it later, but could you tell me how a standard widget or view could be adapted to a custom layout?